# If we use MRC in objective c what is the retain count of sushiName and sushiString . And what about _sushiTypes?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, reference-counting

```
NSString * sushiName = [_sushiTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
NSString * sushiString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %@", 
    indexPath.row, sushiName];
```

If we use MRC in objective c what is the retain count of `sushiName` and `sushiString`?
And what about `_sushiTypes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

- The call to `objectAtIndex` does not transfer ownership to your code (so, in effect, the retain count is unchanged). If you want to make sure the object is not deallocated if it is removed from the array (or if the array itself is deallocated), you need to claim ownership with `retain`.
- The `sushiString` references an autorelease object returned by `stringWithFormat`, which has not transferred ownership to your code. So, if you don't want it deallocated when the autorelease pool is drained, again, you must `retain` it yourself.
- Re `_sushiTypes`, we can't say, because you haven't shared how you instantiated that and/or anything you might be doing to claim ownership of that array.

---

For more information, see [Advanced Memory Management: Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1):

> The memory management model is based on object ownership. Any object may have one or more owners. As long as an object has at least one owner, it continues to exist. If an object has no owners, the runtime system destroys it automatically. To make sure it is clear when you own an object and when you do not, Cocoa sets the following policy:
>
> - **You own any object you create**
>
>   You create an object using a method whose name begins with “`alloc`”, “`new`”, “`copy`”, or “`mutableCopy`” (for example, [`alloc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571958-alloc), [`newObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsobjectcontroller/1535921-newobject), or [`mutableCopy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418978-mutablecopy)).
> - **You can take ownership of an object using `retain`**
>
>   A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the object to its invoker. You use `retain` in two situations: (1) In the implementation of an accessor method or an `init` method, to take ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2) To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some other operation (as explained in [Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000922)).
> - **When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**
>
>   You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a [`release`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571957-release) message or an [`autorelease`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571951-autorelease) message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as “releasing” an object.
> - **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**
>
>   This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated explicitly.

A few final observations:

1. If you're worried about your memory management in Objective-C MRC world, the static analyzer (press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choose "Analyze" from "Product" menu) is remarkably good at identifying issues. Make sure you have a clean bill of health from the static analyzer before doing anything else.
2. `NSString` has all sorts of internal performance enhancements that may make strings appear to outlive what you'd expect from the basic memory management rules (above). Be wary of drawing broader conclusions from any empirical tests with `NSString` objects. They don't behave like other objects.
3. I’d suggest you don’t think about retain counts, but rather think about “ownership” as alluded to in the above quote. See the [Advanced Memory Management Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for such a great answer.I have one more question .Can we retain only one object or index of an array ?

Comment: "Can we retain only one object or index of an array?" ... First, you don't retain indexes of an array. Indexes are not objects and you can only retain objects. Second, in answer to the other question, you retain an array and an array automatically retains everything you add to that array (until you remove it from the array or release the whole array). But if you have some object that you both use in an array as well as need to claim ownership somewhere else, that's fine and it will be retained twice.

Comment: Sorry i want to accept but i am waiting the replay of my commit.